# How to call Smarty in PHP

Tags: php, smarty

How can I call a Smarty `{$Artikel->cArtNr}` inside `{php} {/php}` ?
Is there anyway to do that?

I am running a Smarty engined System and all is built in Smarty.

```
{php}   

// Inputs
$shorturl = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']  . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$signature = "1234567";
$siteurl = "http://test.it";
$articlenumber = $Artikel->cArtNr;

// Phases url
$yourlsinput = "".$siteurl."/yourls-api.php?action=shorturl&url=".$shorturl."&signature=".$signature."" ;

// Open phased url
$fh = fopen($yourlsinput, 'r') or die("can't open file");
//$yourlsoutput = fread($fh,filesize($yourlsinput));
$yourlsoutput = fread($fh,1024);
fclose($fh);

// Converts xml to php array
$xml = simplexml_load_string($yourlsoutput);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

// Output status
echo "<body><p><b>Status:</b> ".$array['status']."<br>";
echo "<b>Message:</b> ".$array['message']."<br>";
echo "<b>Short url:</b> <a href='".$array['shorturl']."'>".$array['shorturl'] . $Artikel->cArtNr."</a></p>";
{/php}
```

Comment: show what you tried so far...?

Comment: Editd for more details

Comment: One of the main purposes of Smarty is to not do the string concatenation you've got in those bottom lines at all.

Comment: Thats why I am asking how I can call Smarty variables in PHP?

Comment: $articlenumber = $this->get_template_vars('cArtNr'); this might helpful for you @karadayi.

Comment: Thanks Yash but it did not help me.. Look around about get_template_vars but I think $Artikel should be declared too. Maybe something like here `$Artikel->GetSmarty()->$this->get_template_vars('cArtNr');` ?